# Чем контролировать сеть

Tags: windows, windows-7

Мне нужно контролироватьследующие программы

АвастГугл хромСкайпИ прочую гугловскую лабуду

т.е. все эти программы, даже при отключенных обновлениях сливают данные куда то там

Как я могу заблокировать все отсылы из них?

посоветуйте профессиональный софт, можно платный именно проверенный, который и лучше не американский, который показывает какая программа куда коннектится и можно через нее заблокировать эти коннекты

Comment: начните с неамериканской ОС )

Answer (score 4):

Посоветую для начала почитать про [Межсетевой экран](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD), после этого про [Сетевой шлюз](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7), а потом решить, что проще настраивать. По моему мнению проще правильно настроить шлюз, но в вашей ситуации всё может быть иначе.

```
Как я могу заблокировать все отсылы из них?
```

решается элементарно на уровне шлюза не запрещением неизвестных хостов и портов, а разрешением известных.

И, кстати, чуть не забыл, возможно более гибко всё может решить использование [прокси сервера](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80). Его можно развернуть как на шлюзе, так и отдельно стоя́щим (это позволит указывать его в настройках программ, тем самым не разрешать всему подряд изнутри системы получать интернет). А анализ логов прокси-сервера может быть более информативным в сравнении с логами шлюзовых фаерволов, таких как iptables или ipfw и может лучше помочь обнаруживать утечки и управлением трафиком.

Answer (score 0):

Ну решение в лоб. Запускайте нужную вам программу от нужного пользователя, и поставьте правило в iptables и модуля owner, тогда сможете отслеживать/блокировать трафик этой программы.

Comment: ой тут windows. Но ответ оставлю.

Comment: Еще больший в_лоб - выдернуть линк, смотрящий в тырент!;)

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый, что-бы не было необходимости что-то запрещать, следует это не устанавливать.
Проверить софт можно снифером - я использую wireshark (есть версия для винды). Он подскажет, что откуда льется - только сначала выучите как писать фильтры для него.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - прокси поставить.

Answer (score -1):

А их исходный код вскрыт? Известны порты отсылки? Скайп вообще невозможно отловить, ибо нет одного сервера и порты генерятся каждый раз новые. Если хотите иметь 100% уверенность в том, что вас "не слушают", поднимайте свои серверы со своими службами. Эта задача не является исполнимой!

Comment: мне нужно просто запретить полностью выход программы в сеть вот и всечтоб если даже чтото отсылает то в никуда, допустим чтобы самой программе казалось что просто нет подключения к интернетудаже платная версия гугла постоянно отсылает чтото, зачем платить деньги если все данные сливаются, а потом всплавают в лучшем случае в виде рекламы

Comment: или вот может есть программа, которая вообще запрещает доступ в сеть всего и вся, и в ней я могу разрешить например доступ в сеть браузеру и необходимых мне программдопустим использовать прокси и аномайзеры бестолку, так как даже тот же самый аваст все стразу сливаетэто просто бред полнейшийдля гугла не бред, единыжды идентифицировав пользователя, он так и остается все тем же пользователем, сколько бы програмок не использовал типа tor и т.д.отсюда только один выход, нужна программа которая контролирует сетьну блин, я думал есть фирмы типа антивирусных которые этим занимаются

Comment: Ideco ICS - нужен выделенный сервер

Comment: Есть, в том числе, сертификат ФСТЭК, модули DLP и прочие прибамбасы. Надежнее решения я не встречал из файрволов. Несмотря на стоимость, капиталовложения много раз себя уже оправдали

Comment: @fhgfjghkfd, в скайпе удаленный рабочий стол был всегда. Вы должны дать разрешение на его использование, никто удаленно сам включить его не может.